# Event Parameters in Flurry Analytics; iPhone app

Tags: iphone, flurry

Trying to get Flurry analytics working in my iPhone app.

I begin a timed event like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *eventDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"0", @"PARAMETER1", 
@"0", @"PARAMETER2", 
nil];
[FlurryAPI logEvent:@"MY_EVENT" withParameters:eventDict timed:YES];
```

At the conclusion of the timed event, I do this:

```
[eventDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", parameter1] forKey:@"PARAMETER1"];
[eventDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", parameter2] forKey:@"PARAMETER2"];
[FlurryAPI endTimedEvent:@"MY_EVENT" withParameters:eventDict];
```

The parameters show up just fine in the event logs but if I try to view the parameters via the Event Parameters link/widget in their web dashboard, I get this message:

**You currently have no event parameters to track**

Tried posting the event as a regular, non-timed event and it made no difference.

Anyone have any idea how I get my event parameters recognized as actual event parameters that I can analyze them in the dashboard. Or is this Event Parameters widget something they don't even have working yet? Or do I just not understand what Event Parameters are supposed to provide?

The Flurry web site is practically no help at all.

TIA

Comment: Dave L is right. The event parameters take a good while to show up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It can take a few hours for event parameters to be updated.  If you've just added them recently, try again in a few hours.

Comment: For reference, I've been waiting 18 hours so far. So looks like it can take longer than just a few hours.

Comment: The parameters refresh is extremely slow - it can take more than 24 hours to get it updated

Comment: You also have to be careful when using XCode and stopping the app. Your events may never be sent. See my answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821996/flurry-events-not-showing-up-at-all/16777465#16777465)

Comment: @Dave L. well for me its been two days..The event is updated but not the parametres

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's usually the case that events show in Event Log (with parameters available to view) long before they show in the Event Parameters view. I've never seen the Event Parameters view show data until at least 24 hours after the event.

It's not really fit for purpose, but it's free so it's popular.

(I know this question is 3 years old but the issue is still happening now, so it seemed worth restating)