# Working with Flurry

Tags: xcode

I have a problem. I include the *flurry.h*  and *libflurry.a* files in my project written in objective c. Then i  add *SystemConfiguration.framework* to my app. Then in *Application Delegate:file* I import  *Flurry.h* and inside *applicationDidFinishLaunching* add: *[Flurry startSession:@"MY_KEY"]*;

In my mainViewController I write this function, when I click in my button call this function.

```
(IBAction)Push:(id)sender {

    [Flurry setUserID:@"Flurry"];
    [Flurry setAge: 22];
    [Flurry setGender:@"m"];
    [Flurry logEvent:@"I just clicked Push!!!"];
    NSLog(@"button clicked!!!");

}
```

But in my flurry.com account I can not see any changes. What can I do

Answer (score 1):

Flurry takes a few hours to update (I found that there is an delay of about ten hours).

Try again later.

Comment: Check out www.AskingPoint.com (Im cofounder), it will soon be very close to real-time!

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your `Push:` method is called. Then check your internet connection. Then check app key that you use.

Answer (score 1):

Note this from the documentation of `startSession`:

*If testing on a simulator, please be sure to send App to background via home button. Flurry depends on the iOS lifecycle to be complete for full reporting.*

Comment: This is probably the issue. Also make sure you're not calling from a background thread. See detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821996/flurry-events-not-showing-up-at-all/16777465#16777465)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this.

```
#import "FlurryAnalytics.h"

(IBAction)Push:(id)sender {

    [Flurry setUserID:@"Flurry"];
    [Flurry setAge: 22];
    [Flurry setGender:@"m"];
    [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"I just clicked Push!!!"];
    NSLog(@"button clicked!!!");

}
```