# Flurry 4.2.2 SDK not sending events session data in iOS

Tags: ios, events, sdk, tracking, flurry

I know that there is a delay in Flurry reporting, however, we are seeing no results the following day on Flurry's reporting.

```
    [Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry setLogLevel:FlurryLogLevelDebug];
    [Flurry startSession:_appSettings.flurryAppId];
    [Flurry setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry setEventLoggingEnabled:YES];
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [Flurry logEvent:@"SESSION_START"
      withParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[device systemVersion], @"OS", nil]
               timed:YES];
```

Our logs show the individual Flurry log calls occurring within the app. What we do ***NOT*** see is anything suggesting that the information is sent to Flurry.

Both `setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled:` and `setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:` are set to `YES` but there is no communication to Flurry of session data when the app is paused or closed. When I restart the app, Flurry attempts to send session data that unfortunately results in:

```
FlurrySession: Add crashed former session
```

As instructed, we started the Flurry session in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method of your AppDelegate
```

According to Flurry's website, we are not tracking any **Events**.

We are using Flurry 4.2.2 SDK

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue which seems to be unique to Flurry SDK 4.2.2:

In 4.2.2 there is a new method:

```
+ (void)setBackgroundSessionEnabled:(BOOL)setBackgroundSessionEnabled;
```

It automatically gets set to `YES` if there are any `UIBackgroundModes` for your app. Our app uses the GPS in the background. Therefore Flurry will never post session data when going to the background.

When I force `[Flurry setBackgroundSessionEnabled:NO];` then it sends up the session data when the Home Button is pressed and the app goes to the background.

I am not sure how this could ever work otherwise. We don't have a need to use Flurry to update GPS locations so this can work for us now.

Hopefully this helps others struggling with this problem.

**Update: 6/17/2014:**

I found more on this in Flurry's [FAQ](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ#I.27ve_just_upgraded_to_iOS_SDK_4.2.2_or_4.2.3_and_have_noticed_a_decline_in_my_Event_counts._What_might_be_the_cause_of_this.3F)

Comment: 1+ I have my app using UIBackgroundModes and it is not posting any events to Flurry using the 4.2.2 SDK. Thanks!