# Maxiumum number of custom events in Flurry analytics?

Tags: ios, flurry

What is the maximum number of custom events you can report per session with Flurry analytics?

Answer (score 10):

The number of events you can report per session in Flurry is 1000. I asked this question to Flurry support, as I couldn't find it elsewhere (and none of the answers here really answered the question). They answered and also sent me a short document titled "Flurry Methodology and Best Practices" that contained, among other things, this summary:

- 300 unique events per app
- 1000 events max per session
- 100 unique event names per session
- 10 params max per event
- Key/Value for params must be Strings
- Key max length 255 chars
- Value max length 255 chars

As the definition of "session" is important, I quote, from the same document:

> Flurry analytics is based on a session model that only “phones home”
>   at the launch and backgrounding of a session. This prevents
>   “talkiness” from the SDK, conserves battery by not always running the
>   radios and allows data to travel in a coherent package."
>
> (...)
>
> One addition to the Flurry session model is the concept that a user
>   may bounce out of an app for a very brief time and reenter the app and
>   still be within the original session. A time may be set, in millis,
>   that is colloquially referred to as the “session timeout”.  It is
>   configurable at app launch (see setContinueSessionMillis for more
>   details) within a range of 5 seconds to 1 minute with a default of 10
>   seconds.  If, when the user comes back into the app, the “session
>   timeout” has not been exceeded, then the SDK will treat the “new”
>   session as a continuation of the former session.
>
> Upon this new launch, if there are any sessions not sent, they will be
>   sent.  At that time, as well, the SDK will make a decision on whether
>   or not to continue a session or start a new one.

[The document is here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxhkbfpuusrdocc/FlurryMethodologyandBestPractices.pdf?dl=0) Flurry support sent it to me in late February, 2015.

Answer (score 5):

The limit appears to be 300 different event ids, and therefore 300 custom events. Quoting: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart

> Your application is currently limited to counting occurrences for 300
>   different Event ids (maximum length 255 characters).

Addional [details from here](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/Events#Are_there_limits_to_the_number_of_Events_and_Parameters_I_can_create.3F)

> Yes, there is a limit of 300 Events for each application. Each event
>   can have up to 10 parameters, and each parameter can have any number
>   of values.

Comment: I think that's something slightly different, that's regarding the number of different types of custom events you can use per session, I'm interested in how many overall custom events of any type you can report per session.

Comment: Thanks, but the info you link to is still not very clear, as they refer to creating events, not reporting events, so again that could mean you can set up 300 different types of event, all of which can be reporting during a session, but i'm interested in how many events of any type can be reported during a session. Perhaps it is 300 (although that doesn't seem many) but it's not clear.

Comment: @Phil You probably should have made your question a bit more clear if you were expecting an answer different then the one 0x7fffffff gave you. It appears to me that he answered your question spot on. (+1 for answer btw).

Comment: @Firo No I think my question is worded perfectly fine thanks.

Comment: Links are dead now. Are those the same as for all kinds of platforms (Android too) ? Maybe this is the latest one: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/faq/events/ ? But it doesn't say about max characters for event names.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is infinite:

> Each Event can have up to 10 parameters, and each parameter can have
>   an infinite number of values associated with it. For example, for the
>   ‘Author’ parameter, there may be 1,000 possible authors who wrote an
>   article. We can keep track of each author via this single parameter.

So if you can have an infinite number of values you could have 10 million authors. Since they are all just values each one can be tracked (via the parameter). If they "can keep track of each author via this single parameter" then I don't think your event count would be mitigated. This would assume you setup your event types properly like in their example:

```
NSDictionary *articleParams =
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"John Q", @"Author", // Capture author info
      @"Registered", @"User_Status", // Capture user status
      nil];

[Flurry logEvent:@"Article_Read" withParameters:articleParams];
```

One event with a maximum of 10 dictionary items, with an infinite number of possible values... I think it would be safe to say you aren't limited here.

Comment: @Phil You can always contact their support line. In relation to your post: I am guessing the `300 event names` is composed of `200 events and up to 100 unique event names` which would be the 300 given in 0x7fffffff answer. I do not believe the developer's response would rule out my answer. Also if you were really concerned you could do some investigative work yourself and test it.

Comment: Just as a heads up, if you're trying to track data through a funnel with this method, it won't work natively in Flurry. e.g. If you have a bunch of screens and you're trying to see how many screens users generally go through, you'd have one of your parameters as "screen number". But you can't do a native funnel in Flurry based on this parameter. You can only do Funnels/User Paths based on events.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of 300 Events for each app. Each event can have up to 10 parameters, and each parameter can have any number of values. Please check all details [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/faq/events/)